# Producer-consumer with conditional variable

Tags: c

I'm looking at the standard solution for the consumer producer problem using conditional variables (this one from the Stanford U website)

```
char buffer[SIZE];
int count = 0, head = 0, tail = 0;
struct lock l;
struct condition notEmpty;
struct condition notFull;

lock_init(&l);
condition_init(&notEmpty);
condition_init(&notFull);

void put(char c) {
    lock_acquire(&l);
    while (count == SIZE) {
        condition_wait(&notFull, &l);
    }
    count++;
    buffer[head] = c;
    head++;
    if (head == SIZE) {
        head = 0;
    }
    condition_signal(&notEmpty, &l);
    lock_release(&l);
}

char get() {
    char c;
    lock_acquire(&l);
    while (count == 0) {
        condition_wait(&notEmpty, &l);
    }
    count--;
    c = buffer[tail];
    tail++;
    if (tail == SIZE) {
        tail = 0;
    }
    condition_signal(&notFull, &l);
    lock_release(&l);
    return c;
}
```

My question is why would I need two conditions? Why it's not gonna work with just one? When the buffer is full it will signal the consumer and when the buffer is empty it will signal the producer, using the same signal.

Comment: can you explain why? every thread will acquire the mutex at his scheduled time

Comment: If we use same signal, It will tell both consumer and producer that "Something is happened". Both will need to run an addional logic to make sure "What" happened. Two signals will reduce this burden.

Comment: You seem to be begging the question.   Why did you come to the conclusion that two were *needed*?

Comment: because I got hangs with only one condition